# How to understanding "Calls+RecurCalls/Total" in Android TraceView tool

Tags: android, android-traceview

In many article, Calls+Recur Calls/Total is simply explained as "the number of calls and repeat calls". Yes, it could clearly explain the meaning of values like "1 + 0", but I can not get to know the meaning for values like "1/441". See attached

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The 1/3 in your image is easy to understand: Your MainActivity.methodA() calls Thread.sleep() once, and Thread.sleep() is called three times in total (ie. once by methodA() and twice by other callers). Click the sleep() line if you want to see the three callers in the 'parents' area.